# how to retrieve a variable from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In my `php` file I call a link with `jquery`. That link contains a select list with an input text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        var linkUsers='<div id="selectUsers"><select name="selectUsers" ><option value="">Select a ...</option><option value="LASTNAME">LASTNAME</option><option value="FIRSTNAME">FIRSTNAME</option><option value="ZIPCODE">ZIPCODE</option><option value="EMAIL">EMAIL</option><option value="STATUS">STATUS</option><option value="LICENSE">LICENSE</option><option value="OTHER">OTHER</option></select><br><br> </div><div><input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext"> <br><br>';

        $(wrapper).append(linkUsers);
```

I want to retrieve the value of `selectUser` and `mytext` and put them in a database or `php` variable.

I tried to see if I can have the correct result with `jquery` so I used alert and it display the right value.

```
`//when the user choose an option in the select list 
$('#selectUsers select').change(function(){
        tableselect = $(this).val() ;
        alert(tableselect[$i]);`
```

What I want to do is to retrieve this value and to put it in a database and to retrieve the input text written by the user (I have no idea how to do that ? how to detect that user has filled the blank ?)

The other problem is that I call the `jquery` link as many as the user want so it will be useful to put the value of `selectUser` and `mytext` in an array variable but I don't know how !

If someone can help me U will be grateful. THANKS A LOT !

Comment: What the user does happens in the client, so you need to send the user's data back to your server. This can happen in a lot of ways - the most common ones are: Submitting a form, AJAX call, WebSocket. Go pick the one you want and start from there.

Comment: Use ajax to pass data in php for update record.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note : wrapper not specified as class or id ,replace according to that.i am assuming as id
```

you can pick the value of select box and input like this .
    For select : 
    Note : add id on select box ,for now i have added  "selectUsers"

```
$("#wrapper").on("change","#selectUsers",function(){
     alert($(this).val());
    });

For input : 



 $("#wrapper").on("keyup","#mytext",function(){
     alert($(this).val());
    });

then you can send this response by ajax to php file ands store into db.
you can change event according to need.
Hope this will help you.
```

Comment: try moving the text outside code blocks so it is easier to read and only put code in code blocks

Answer (score 0):

This is the jQuery ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#selectUsers select').change(function(){
        tableselect = jQuery(this).val() ;
            var data_pro = {
                    action: 'update_record',
                    tableselect: tableselect
                    };

                    jQuery.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType : 'html',
                                url: ajaxurl,
                                data: data_pro,
                                  success: function(data){

                                    }
                            });

    });
    });
</script>
```

this is the php function put it in your functions.php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_record', 'update_record');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_record', 'update_record');

         function local_pickup_shipping_options(){
         print_r($_POST['tableselect']);
             }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue